# Boolean flag in Windows Service not working

Tags: multithreading, windows-services

Sorry for my bad English, would appreciate if anyone can help me to fix.

I have written a Windows Service to get Transactions from the database and export them to flat file to send to another system via sftp. This service has been run for 6 months without any problem. My code is something as below:

I used a boolean variable named `_isProcessOutwardMessage` to check if a thread is running to start a new thread (`processOutwardMessageThread`). There were 5 flags and 5 threads like this (but I have removed 4 to keep my post short)

My problem is: After about 6 months running, the IT guys did something in the server (he said it is hardening). Since this update, my service has faced an error. When I check the log, I found that the same Thread (ex: `processOutwardMessageThread`) has been executed twice at the same time (it looks like the flag is not working anymore). It is wrong because it can only be run after the previous thread completed (flag has been set to false).

I have tried to restart the service, but it only works fine around 1 hour, after that, it cause the error again. Please give me some advice. Thanks

```cs
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace FastOne.Payment.MessageService
{
    internal partial class ProcessMessageService : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer _processOutwardMessageTimer;

        public ProcessMessageService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoadConfiguration()
        {
            try
            {                
                _processOutwardMessageInterval =
                    int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessOutwardMessageInterval"]);               

                //Running flag
                _isProcessOutwardMessage = false;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ProcessServiceLogger.Error(exception);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {            
            //Load configs
            LoadConfiguration();

            _processOutwardMessageTimer = new Timer(_processOutwardMessageInterval);
            _processOutwardMessageTimer.Elapsed += ProcessOutwardMessageTimer_Elapsed;
            _processOutwardMessageTimer.Start();            
        }

        private void ProcessOutwardMessageTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isProcessOutwardMessage)
            {
                var processOutwardMessageThread = new Thread(ProcessOutwardMessage);
                processOutwardMessageThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private void ProcessOutwardMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessOutwardMessageWithTransaction();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ProcessOutwardMessageLogger.Info("FAILED! ROLLBACK TRANSACTION!");
                ProcessOutwardMessageLogger.Error(exception);
            }
        }

        private void ProcessOutwardMessageWithTransaction()
        {
            //Set flag to true
            _isProcessOutwardMessage = true;

            //Do something here
            WriteLogToFile("Thread Execute.");

            //Set flag to false
            _isProcessOutwardMessage = false;            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is susceptible to failure because there is a large "window of opportunity" for race conditions.

Consider this potential scenario:

1. Thread #1's timer elapses and **ProcessOutwardMessageTimer_Elapsed()** is called
2. **_isProcessOutwardMessage** is false, so "**var processOutwardMessageThread = new Thread(ProcessOutwardMessage)**" is invoked
3. While Thread #1 (and the system) are creating the new thread, which can take several milliseconds to complete, Thread #2's timer goes off
4. Thread #2 sees that **_isProcessOutwardMessage** is false, so it calls "**var processOutwardMessageThread = new Thread(ProcessOutwardMessage)**".
5. Thread #3 and Thread #4 are eventually created (by Thread #1 and Thread #2 respectively) and both call **ProcessOutwardMessageWithTransaction()**.

Your processing is executed twice.

The problem is that the "window" between where you check for and where you set the boolean gatekeeper is way too large. Checking and setting the gatekeeper should be as close to a single (atomic) operation as possible. The larger the window between check and set, the greater the potential for race conditions.

[Synchronization objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) were created to help solve that problem. I suggest that you incorporate them into your solution.